# find posts which are posted from last month

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am working on meteor and i have this small problem.I'm sure many of you know the answer.

I'm using mongodb

I want posts which are posted from last month same date to till know

like

```
today 3 march
```

i want posts which are posted from

`feb 3 to march 3`

i inserted a date field in document like this

```
var dat=new Date();
```

Can we do it using Date field or do we need to store any other fields.

How to achieve it i have no ideas.

Thx in advance

Comment: What would you do for March 30th? February 27th or February 28th?

Comment: @Firo thx for the reply,yeah good question. Otherwise return posts which are posted in last 30 days

Answer (score 1):

According the [official mongodb documentation](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/), you can try this:

```
var end = new Date(); // today
var start = new Date().setMonth(end.getMonth() - 1); // last month
db.posts.find({created_on: {$gte: start, $lt: end}});
```

Comment: Thx for the reply,In my app,i don't know start and end time they have to generate automatically is that possible?